# Load external https url in angularjs mobile app without iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, same-origin-policy

I want to load a https url inside a angularjs mobile app. I do not want to use iframe. I tried ajax but I get issues with same origin policy (nothing loads up). I tried in the inappBrowser but that does not really load within a div of an app. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: You cant make AJAX request across boundary of origin without allowance of server.

Answer (score 0):

You can make cross domain AJAX requests if you allow access origin to wildcard.

For PHP;

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

But be aware of security concerns.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. But I dont have a backend. I want to load public http/https external url inside my app.